# how to tell NuGet to install package per project and not solution

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I have a class library project which is reused across different solutions.
I would like NuGet to add a toolkit reference to the class library project and store it in the project folder not in the solution folder.

Example:

I have

> D:\Projects\MyClassLibrary
>
> D:\Projects\Solution1
>
> D:\Projects\Solution2

Using NuGet, I want to add a toolkit to the MyClassLibrary project.

Right now, if I have Solution1 open, NuGet is adding the toolkit to

> D:\Projects\Solution1\packages

I would like to tell NuGet to install the toolkit in the `MyClassLibrary\packages` folder instead.

How to do this?

Comment: So another way of stating your goal is that you want to store the packages of some solutions in the packages folder of a particular solution (your question is a little confusing because you mention "projects" containing solutions, but in C#-land it's usually the other way around.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default packages folder location since nuget 2.1:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key=" repositoryPath" value=" C:\myteam\teampackages" />
  </config>
  ... 
</configuration>
```

reference: [Specify ‘packages’ Folder Location](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.1#Specify_%e2%80%98packages%e2%80%99_Folder_Location)

-----------------UPDATE-------------------------

you have to enable [nuget automatic package restore](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages) for the solution.
When you do it nuget create a `.nuget` folder in the solution root.

Inside that folder there are the file `NuGet.Config` where you can put this configuration.

-----------------(last) UPDATE 2020-------------------------

nuget has changed since and this answer does not apply anymore

Comment: where do I put that xml file? I tried to put it under the 'D:\Projects\MyClassLibrary' and it didnt work

Comment: the NuGet Automatic Package Restore option is already set. there is no '.nuget' folder in the solution folder, only 'packages' folder. I don't think NuGet works how I wanted to.

Comment: I'm using the latest version; I will mark your answer as answer to thank for your comments. But it doesn't address my problem

Comment: @OpCoder thanks! try to create a new solution and enable package restore and then copy the .nuget folder