# Project to take files from it's own folder

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have a web application that consists of the BaseApp, and plugins which are added for each client. BaseApp is just an MVC project, as are the plugins. Each project has it's own views, scripts, etc. To develop for each client, we create a new solution. So, let's say that one client's solution consists of BaseApp and PluginA projects, and for the other it is BaseApp and PluginB. My problem here is that BaseApp, even though it has all the files in it's folder structure, will in .csproj file write includes from one or the other client's solution folders. That includes both nuget packages, and static content. This is problematic since the developer working on code for one client, should have the solution for both clients.
So, is there a way to configure project to look for views, scripts and other content only inside it's own folder?

Comment: Just to clarify; you don't want the BaseApp project to include any references to the client 'plugin' projects?

Comment: Yes, and it will not. The problem is that nuget packages get installed per solution, and not per project. I find this one, and it will help, I will just have to reinstall few packages - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269801/how-to-tell-nuget-to-install-package-per-project-and-not-solution
SolutionDir is the last variable that still lefts in, but it will be set per solution and it will not create any problems.